# Android version of code not working like desktop internet browsers

Tags: php, javascript, android

I have website code that I have been testing on android, but when I compare it to the results from the desktop running the same code with the same parameters it shows that it isn't working on the android.

I have looked over the code with the change of results and have a timeframe where things go wrong. The options are either that the PHP runs incorrectly (which it would be nice to confirm, but this can't possibly be the problem because PHP runs server side meaning either both android and desktop would act the same) or the Javascript is not taking information from the fields on the page correctly.

If it is the second case, the information is being taken from `<option value ="importantpart">` of a `<select>` and from input of an `<input type="text">`.

Is there any specific way that I have to take information from those two places. Also, in a related but question, would there need to be a similar change for iOS browser or would the same change work.

Currently it is being obtained while the javascript runs in the form

```
var whatever = $("#fieldID").val();
```

Comment: How does that code not work in the iOS browser?

Comment: I don't know about iOS browser, I've only seen it from an android browser, the question if a similar change is needed to make it work for iOS as it would for android

Comment: ...or the android browser, then. What does not work there that works on a desktop?

Comment: I assume you are using jQuery, this should work fine on both Android and iOS. Is your site live? Can we see it?

Comment: Essentially I am pulling information from PHP using those inputs as a basis. No matter what I do on the android I end up in the situation where nothing was found by the PHP code, even though I have results for the same inputs when I run on Chrome(and IE and presumably Firefox)

Comment: http://tripanomaly.com/221-2/

Comment: Works on my Galaxy Nexus is there a specific page it doesn't work on?

Comment: Alkyl, when you say it works, do you mean you can run the reliability checker and get a result where it says there is a flight(American Airlines Flight 123 usually shows up as a valid flight)

Comment: I just tested it on my (very slow) AVD Android Emulator, is it possible that my phone's Javascript/PHP abilities are another of the casualties of Verizon's editing to the latest Xperia Play update

Answer (score 0):

- Try dumping $_REQUEST, $_GET and $_POST to a log file and do the same request from your desktop and your android.
- Are there any differences? Watch out for minor differences like line breaks, and spaces!